# Can not install apk, got navigated to Security page when tap on apk

Tags: apk

I need to install apk on my Motorola android 7, no root. 
I did enable `allow install app from unknown source`
I dont have any screen filtering app running on my phone (so other thread on this topic doesnt work).
Everytime i tap on apk. The `security` page show up, not the install button.

Comment: How are you installing? Source - sideloading or other repositories? Also please add a screenshot of security page, and Android version details by [edit]

Comment: maybe side loading, I've download an apk from a website and need to install it.

Comment: Try troubleshooting using [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat).